# Do Python tuples really need to be ordered?

Tags: python, tuples, built-in

I'm still new to Python and I've read multiple times that python tuples **are** "ordered" per se, like here on W3Schools site: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp. I've also noticed that Python documentation doesn't say anything about it needing to be "ordered". I tried creating an unordered tuple and this is what I got:

[image: Unordered tuple]

I did this w/ this line:

```
tup = (2, 8, 3)
```

So tuples doesn't need to be ordered?

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact that "ordered" and "sorted" are different things.

Comment: @Selcuk aren't those the same? Sorry English is not my native language

Comment: No. Ordered means that once created they will keep the same order no matter what. As an example, it is guaranteed that `tup[1]` is equal to `8` for your your `(2, 8, 3)` tuple.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Those questions have already been clarified. You should read the comments and the answers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What I mean is that the question is perfectly valid as it is and all the information required to answer is supplied in the question. It's just you don't seem to have understood what the question is, and the comments would have helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss-understood meaning of `ordered`. By ordered documentation means that information about order of elements within tuple is stored inside data structure. NOT that elements of tuple are in sorted order.

As opposed to `unordered` when information about order of elements is not stored in data structure and not preserved, i.e. `unordered` data structure sorts elements before storing it inside internal memory hence loses information about order of elements of original source data.

You probably think that `ordered` means that elements are sorted inside tuple, i.e. you may think that `(3, 7, 9, 15)` is ordered but `(9, 7, 15, 3)` is not.

Tuple is stored as a sequence of its elements in memory. Hence always `ordered`. Like array are also always ordered. But some structures may not keep order of elements, for example lets represent a set of numbers, with bit vector, `bit(i) == 1` if and only if `i` is in set, otherwise bit is 0. Thus `0 0 1 0 1` represents set of numbers `{2, 4}`. This structure is unordered, meaning that order is not preserved due to form of representation. In other words `unordered` means that it is stored in memory always sorted.

Comment: OH now I see, I thought that ordered = sorted. So an unordered data structure would be a set?

Comment: @Milky Yes set is unordered. In mathematical meaning. Of cause each language may or may not keep order of set. For instance if set is stored just as array of its unique elements in memory in original order then language still keeps info about order of set, hence may be thought as ordered. But if it is kept as bit vector (as described in my answer) then there is no info about ordering, hence it is unordered for sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Tuple** is a collection which is **ordered** and **unchangeable**. **Allows duplicate members**. In Tuple, ordered collection means Tuple does record order of the elements it received and stores it as is. Does not allow changing the position/item assignments.

```
>>> tup = (2,2,8,3)
>>> tup
(2, 2, 8, 3)
```

**Set** is a collection which is **unordered** and **unindexed**. **No duplicate members.** Sets, being an unordered collection meaning sets do not record element position or order of insertion.

```
>>> sample_set = { 2,2,8,3 }
>>> sample_set
{8, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "ordered" means. A `tuple` is an immutable sequence. It is built from some other sequence or generator and whatever order that thing iterated its values is the order you get in the `tuple`.

So, a `tuple` isn't ordered in the sense of a sorted order - its just the time order in which items were added during construction.